# incorrect type not detected by typescript compiler?

Tags: typescript, compiler-warnings, downcast

Here is a simple example.

I'm using this kind of design for a MVC architecture: you can think of M (and derived classes) as a model and V (and derived classes) as a view:

```
abstract class M { abstract update() : void; }
abstract class V { abstract updateView (m: M) : void; }

class M1 implements M {
    fV: V;
    fName: string;
    constructor () { this.fV = new V1(); this.fName="M1"; }
    getName() : string { return this.fName; }
    update() : void { this.fV.updateView (this); }
}

class M2 implements M {
    fV: V;
    constructor () { this.fV = new V1(); }
    update() : void { this.fV.updateView (this); }
}

// ==> V1 implementation of V is incorrect but not detected by the compiler
class V1 implements V {
    updateView (m: M1) : void { console.log (m.getName() + ": update called"); }
}

var m1 = new M1();
m1.update();

// ==> incorrect use of V1 by M2 not detected at compile time, generates an error at run time
var m2 = new M2();
m2.update();
```

Note that the following generates an error at compile time:

```
abstract class X { abstract amethod () : void; }
class V2 implements V {
    updateView (m: X) : void { console.log ("V2 update called"); }
}
```

Is something wrong with the first code or is there a problem with the compiler?

Thanks in advance for your help

Dom

Answer (score 0):

This compiles for me (ts 1.8.10)

```
abstract class M { abstract update() : void; }
abstract class V { abstract updateView (m: M) : void; }

abstract class X extends M { abstract amethod () : void; }
class V2 implements V {
    updateView (m: X) : void { console.log ("V2 update called"); }
}
```

The change is that X must extend M (since V expects an M in `updateView`)

Comment: Sure, I know. The problem is not with the second part (I don't want that to compile) but with the first example: I don't want that to compile too (but it does).